# IELTS for Canadian permanent residence

Tags: canada, residency, language, ielts, language-test

My IELTS score is as follows
Listening 7
Reading 6.5
Writing 7.5
Speaking 7.5
Over all band score 7
Does it qualify for Canadian permanent residence application

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar marks when I did mine in 2010. It was never a problem. But nobody told me how this all connects. four years later I received my residency.